# Something Simple but Hard to Say

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Something simple but hard to say,

Contradicting myself but heard everyday,

Like finicky faucets that drip,

Or tight trousers that rip,

My applications often lead to people annoyed,

Maybe that's why my letters are rarely deployed.

However, if you know how I'm written,

The sesquipedalians among you can't help but be smitten.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is it:

> **onomatopoeia**, the formation of a word from a sound associated with what is named

Something simple but hard to say,

> Hard to pronounce, but it just means a word that sounds like the sound its describing

Contradicting myself but heard everyday,

> No one hears the word 'onomatopoeia', but they hear what onomatopoeia is

Like finicky faucets that drip,

> 'Drip' is an onomatopoeia

Or tight trousers that rip,

> And so is 'rip'

My applications often lead to people annoyed,

> These sounds make people annoyed, like the buzzing of a fly

Maybe that's why my letters are rarely deployed.

> Cause onomatopoeia is not a word that comes up often in conversation

However, if you know how I'm written,

> Onomatopoeia is hard to spell

The sesquipedalians among you can't help but be smitten.

> Sesquipedalians are people who like long words (or words with multiple syllables)